# RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to predict an image's class but have been getting this error in my code 'RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4'. What's wrong in my code?

I load the model from s3 and trying to predict an image stored in my local storage

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
import sharp from 'sharp';
import 'dotenv/config';

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const modelKey = 'trained_model/model.json';
const getModelParams = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: modelKey,
};

s3.getObject(getModelParams, async (err, modelData) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error getting model from S3:', err);
    } else {
        const modelUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', getModelParams);
        console.log('url', modelUrl);
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelUrl);
        const inputImagePath = 'test.jpg';
        const inputImageBuffer = await sharp(inputImagePath)
            .resize(224, 224)
            .toBuffer();
        const inputImage = tf.node.decodeImage(inputImageBuffer, 3);
        const inputImageExpanded = inputImage.expandDims(0);
        const inputImageNormalized = inputImageExpanded.div(255.0);

        const predictions = model.predict(inputImageNormalized);
        const predictionArray = predictions.dataSync();
        const isNSFW = predictionArray[0] > predictionArray[1];

        if (isNSFW) {
            console.log('The image is NSFW.');
        } else {
            console.log('The image is SFW.');
        }
    }
});
```